# Installshield Installation Requirements (Best Way To Search For An Installed Application)

Tags: installation, installshield, requirements

Going through an installshield project and am wondering what is the best route to go to check if SQL Server is installed as well as Crystal Reports Viewer? I was thinking of checking the registry but not sure if Local_Machine or Current_User is the better option? Or maybe an alternate option altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do a search based on what my actual physical dependency ie.  For example, if I need Oracle Client I search for oci.dll.  It's kind of a case by case basis:

Registry typically costs less.
Hard drive isn't too bad if you search one directory.  Recursive searches are expensive.

SQL Server might not need a search per say.  What exactly is your SQL dependency?  Client Connectivity tools?  A database instance? A certain version or any version?  Same for instance name.  A running database instance that you can actually connect to?

If you are executing SQL scripts against a SQL server, the SqlLogin dialog can be used to establish connectivity.

Comment: A database instance pretty much. Unfortunately no matter what I could not get it to detect by registry entry. Then I would try to create a launch condition based on the file itself but then I realized I couldn't just use [PROGRAMFILES] because my instance was a 64 bit instance and wasn't detected when I chose it. This is with the limited edition visual studio integration. I could use [PROGRAM64FILES] or whatever it is in the full version but then if they are using a 32 bit it fails. I'd have to basically search the entire drive, which is why I wanted by key.

Comment: Any instance or a specific instance?  Do you care if the instance is running or not?  ( The service could exist but not be started. )  Depending on your requirements, you might need a custom action.

Comment: It was any instance and not dependent on if it's running, just installed.